# Can we work on valid I-797 but enter on B1/B2 visa?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, h1b-visas, working-visas

This might be not possible in normal scenario, but we are not normal now, we are COVID victim :).

I had visa till July 28th, I already renew my visa and got I-797 till 2025.

I am planing to go for renew stamp to India in June. I am searching for dates to dropbox in Mumbai consulate. I was trying from 2 weeks, but no success.

Now the real problem, in case, I go to India, and we don't get the appointment date for the drop box. If we come back on our tourist visa (B1/B2, which is valid till 2024), then, Can I legally work as I have valid I-797 till 2025 ?

If we come on B1/B2 visa, we have to go back before 6 months, but at that time, I think we might get the dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An I-797 is not a visa and cannot be used as a visa (which I think you already know).
The only type of I-797 which allows you to travel to the USA is in I-797**F** "Transportation Letter" which (according to [citizenpath.com](https://citizenpath.com/form-i-797-notice-action/#:%7E:text=Form%20I%2D797F%2C%20Transportation%20Letter,is%20lost%2C%20stolen%20or%20mutilated.) is:

> a transportation letter that’s issued overseas to allow applicants to travel to the United States. It’s typically issued to lawful permanent residents (green card holders) who are outside the U.S. and whose green card is lost, stolen or mutilated.

The other types of I-797 "Notice of Action" forms are of no use for travelling to or seeking entry into the USA.

As such, if you attempt to enter the USA with only your I-797 & your B1/B2 visa with the intent to work, you will be denied entry and sent back home.
If you lie about your intent you will almost certainly be caught out, and even if you're not caught you will still not legally be allowed to work, having entered on a tourism/business visa (and remember, business is *not* the same thing as working).
*Either of these will most certainly jeopardize your chances of getting a new visa!*

So, change your plans. Do not leave the USA for visa stamping or any other avoidable reason until such time as you know you are able to get an appointment for a new visa stamp.
Remember, your visa only needs to be valid to allow you to *enter* the USA.
If you've received the I-797 indicating that your renewal application has been received, then you *are still in status* while you remain in the USA - do do not *need* to leave and get a new visa stamped.

Comment: It's a nit, but the insistence that only a I-797F alone is of use for travel to the US isn't entirely correct. The I-797C issued in response to an application to remove conditions for a 2-year green card [includes a 2 year extension of status](https://www.uscis.gov/newsroom/alerts/uscis-extends-evidence-of-status-for-conditional-permanent-residents-to-24-months-with-pending-form) and hence permits travel and entry when presented with the expired gc. The I-94's that were likely attached to the OP's I-797 would be sufficient for short trips to Canada/Mexico. The answer's correct for the OP, tho.